# Get the column name along with column data in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

Basically I have a table ABC:

```
COl1 | Col2 | COl3
---- | ---- | ----
  1  |  a   |  12
  2  |  b   |  11
  1  |  b   |  10
```

I need an answer something like :

```
column name | distinct value of the column | number of occurrences
----------- | ---------------------------- | --------------------
col1        | 1                            | 2
col1        | 2                            | 1
col2        | a                            | 1
col2        | b                            | 2
col3        | 10                           | 1
col3        | 11                           | 1
col3        | 12                           | 1
```

Is there a way to solve this using Teradata?

Comment: Are you looking for SQL to do this, or a solution within Aster?

Comment: So you're basically trying to profile your data?

Comment: I need a SQL which does this..

Answer (score 0):

For your specific example, you could do something like the following:

You basically do a union for each column name.  If your values are different data types you have to cast them to some type that will work for all the values.

```
SELECT ColumnName,DistinctValue, COUNT(*) AS occurrences
FROM
(
SELECT CAST('Col1' AS VARCHAR(4)) AS "ColumnName"
,CAST(Col1 AS VARCHAR(2)) AS "DistinctValue"
FROM ABC
UNION ALL
SELECT CAST('Col2' AS VARCHAR(4)) AS "ColumnName"
,CAST(Col2 AS VARCHAR(2)) AS "DistinctValue"
FROM ABC
UNION ALL
SELECT CAST('Col3' AS VARCHAR(4)) AS "ColumnName"
,CAST(Col3 AS VARCHAR(2)) AS "DistinctValue"
FROM ABC
) MyTable
GROUP BY ColumnName,DistinctValue
ORDER BY ColumnName,DistinctValue
```

If you need to get the column names to use in the above query, you can do something like

```
HELP TABLE ABC;
```

or

```
Select ColumnName from DBC.ColumnsV  
where Tablename='ABC'  
and DatabaseName='YourDatabaseName';
```

If you want something generic that works for any table then you are probably going to create a stored procedure where you query the column names from DBC.ColumnsV and then use the result in a dynamic SQL query.  However, that could get ugly (both in terms of actually writing it and what happens when you run it against a huge table with lots of distinct values).